# Jeffreys prior for linear regression model

Tags: regression, bayesian, references, linear-model

Consider the linear regression model

$${\bf y} = {\bf X}\beta + {\bf e},$$

where ${\bf y}$ is an $n\times 1$ vector, $\beta$ is a $p\times 1$ vector, ${\bf e}$ is an $n\times 1$ vector. Assume also that $e_j\stackrel{ind.}{\sim} N(0,\sigma)$.

What is the Jeffreys prior of the parameters $(\beta,\sigma)$?  I am basically looking for a reference where I can find this.

Comment: If you want your account deleted just flag the question and leave a comment to the moderator to delete your account....

Answer (score 2):

I have found a reference.

The Jeffreys prior in the normal linear regression model is:

$$\pi(\beta,\sigma^2)\propto \dfrac{1}{(\sigma^2)^\frac{p+2}{4}},$$

or more commonly in the $\sigma$ parameterization:

$$\pi(\beta,\sigma)\propto \dfrac{1}{\sigma^\frac{p+2}{2}}.$$

The reference is: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2290514 (see text just after Eq. 2.9 -- a bit hard to read!)

Comment: Most people drop the $(p-2)/2$ term and simply use $$\pi(\beta,\sigma^2)\propto\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$$